# Why does Firefox crash when I view a page with an embedded Java applet?

Tags: macos, mac, firefox, java, crash

My operating system is OS X.  If a page which has a Java applet in it, Firefox crashes.  Safari is works great without any problem on those pages.

What would cause this problem, and how can fix it?

Comment: Please post the error-related output you see in the system Console.

Comment: Which version of OS X and Firefox are you running?

Comment: No feedback from author in 2 years...

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bit obvious, but have you tried deleting the ffox cache, updating java and creating a new ffox profile? Google results for firefox java crash seem to point towards the new profile being a possible fix.

Also try deleting the files in jars in ~/Library/Java/Extensions, as suggested here: http://support.mozilla.com/tiki-view_forum_thread.php?locale=ga-IE&comments_parentId=385394&forumId=1

Comment: There is no jar file in my ~/Library/Java/Extensions but i still delete that but i have same issue.

Comment: update java to the latest versions. then clear cashe (and if you have to back up bookmarks and create a new profile, or even reinstall wiping the old profile)